Example of extension of a non-Archimedean local field where the inertia subgroup is not open
I want to to find an example of an algebraic extension L of an non-Archimedean local field K where the inertia subgroup is not open when viewed in Gal(L/K).
First thing to note is that we need the extension to be infinite o/w we get a discrete topology and everything is open. Secondly we need some ramification o/w the interia subgroup is trivial. We also need it to not be totally ramified otherwise the inertia subgroup is everything.
This leaves me thinking about extensions such as $\mathbb{Q}_p^{ur}(\sqrt{p})/\mathbb{Q}_p$ but I am not sure how to actually compute things here.

A common definition of local fields implies that they are locally compact, thus finite over some $\mathbb{Q}_p$. I’m guessing that you mean an algebraic Galois extension $E/F$ with $F$ algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}_p$? And you’re asking that the inertia subgroup of $E/F$ is not open in $Gal(E/F)$, right?

@Aphelli yes that is correct - i will amend my question

This is kind of cheating, but what about $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}/\mathbb{Q}_p$?

@Aphelli what does Gal and the inertia subgroup look like here? Is there is easy way to tell its not an open subgroup

The inertia subgroup doesn’t have finite index (because it contains an unramified extension of infinite degree) so it’s not open.

Ah I see why now
